# Eigenvalues of $AA^T$ if $A^T A=I_r$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, projection-matrices

Suppose $A$ is a $n \times r$ matrix with $n>r$ and $A^TA=I_r$, i.e., $A$ could be the matrix of eigenvectors of $r$ eigenvalues. I am wondering what's the eigenvalues of $AA^T$, which is of rank $r$ and sum of all eigenvalues of $AA^T$ equals $r$. Any particular formula for the eigenvalues of $AA^T$? Thanks!

Comment: Look up the singular value decomposition. tl;dr the nonzero eigenvalues are the same including multiplicities and the rest (of which there are some in this situation) are just zero.

Comment: confirm $(AA^T)^2 = AA^T$ then take the trace to get the number of eigenvalues = 1, the rest must all be zero... why?

Comment: $$|\lambda I_n-AA^T|=\lambda^{n-r}|\lambda I_r -A^TA|$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: for any $\lambda$ such that $A^T A x = \lambda x$, you have

$$
A^T A x = \lambda x \implies AA^T (Ax) = \lambda (Ax).
$$

Comment: Thanks for that!